# Why doesn't this Javascript succesfully change the background on the second mouseover?

Tags: if-statement, onmouseover

The function is supposed to increment `x` by 1 every time it launches, thus forcing the code to choose a different option on the next launch.

```
function changeBackground() {
  var x = 0;
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    document.getElementById("sample").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("sample").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  x++;
}
var x = document.getElementById("sample");
x.onmouseover = changeBackground;
```

This is just grabbing a heading and launching `changeBackground` every time the cursor is placed on it. The background color stays on **purple**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you set it to 0 every time in the beginning of the function.. you need to set the variable outside of the function

```
var x = 0;
function changeBackground() {
if (x % 2 === 0) {
document.getElementById("sample").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
}
else {
document.getElementById("sample").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
x++;
}
var x = document.getElementById("sample");
x.onmouseover = changeBackground;
```

Comment: That was the problem, thanks. I also noticed I declared x twice.